# Can you define class properties in a loop?

Tags: python, class, iteration

does anyone know if it's possible to define class properties while iterating over a list? For example:

```
class a ():
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.data = df
        property_names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        property_values = [a, b, c, d]

        for i, j in zip(property_names, property_values):
            self.i = self.data.loc[self.data[col].isin(j)]
```

property_values in this example is a list of lists.

I would like for the class to return self.a = df.loc[df[col].isin(a)], and so on.

Thanks,

Comment: The values `self.j` will simply be overwritten.

Comment: Try something like `setattr(self, i, self.data.loc[self.data[col].isin(j)])` (although you have to do something with the `col` variable - it is not defined in your code)

Comment: @KT., let me give that a shot. Is it generally good practice to do it like this? I just want to avoid having multiple lines of code, doing almost the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: `setattr(object, attribute_name, value)` and `getattr(object, attribute_name)` are totally normal ways of addressing object attributes by name. For example, `obj.x = 1` is, in fact, equivalent to `setattr(obj, 'x', 1)`.